# Why are my rails tests so slow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

Is it normal for my test suite to take 5 seconds just to launch? Even when running an empty suite it still takes this long. Is it because it's firing up a new instance of rails on each run? If so, is there anyway to keep it persistent?

Example:

```
rlepidi@rlepidi:~/projects/rails/my_project$ time rake test
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 -I"lib:test" "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/unit/release_test.rb" 
Loaded suite /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started

Finished in 0.000181867 seconds.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
0% passed

real    0m4.173s
user    0m3.820s
sys 0m0.288s
```

As you can see, this empty test is really fast, but there is still 4 seconds of overhead for some reason. I'm using Test::Unit with Shoulda.

Comment: Can you post the output of "time rake test:units --trace"

Comment: for modern rails users: `rails test --profile' will highlight the test speeds - so you can investigate the slow ones. This assumes minitest. I have no idea about rspec.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Test speed bottleneck is the time it takes Rails to load its environment.  Run script/console and see how long it takes to load you into your environment...it should be the same.

One you have a large enough codebase with many plugins & gems, load time can be as high as 1 minute!!
If you are like me & stop running tests b/c you are sick of waiting 30 seconds just to test a small change, you need to run a test server like spec_server, or even better: spork!

You will find that there may be strange issues dealing with class cacheing with spec_server which is why I prefer spork.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it really was just the Rails environment loading. I've switched to Rspec with Spork and it's a bit better.

Comment: try loading the gems but not requiring them right away. Instead require them when they're used and the environment will load much faster.

In Rails 3's Gemfile, this looks something like: 

    gem 'some_gem_name', :lib => nil

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and I resolved it by installing ruby entreprise edition (REE). I don't know why but loading the rails environment took 4-5 seconds under my ruby 1.9.2, vs 1-2 seconds with REE.

I installed it using RVM.

Answer (score 0):

How long does your test run? Usually Rails tests take long due to database access. To speed them up as initial improvement you could:

1. stop using instantiated fixtures by setting:

   self.use_instantiated_fixtures = false
2. start using transactional fixtures by setting:

   self.use_transactional_fixtures = true

To improve tests performance even more please consider using [preloaded fixtures](http://web.elctech.com/2007/05/30/preloading-fixtures/).

Comment: The amount of time the tests take to actually *run* is negligible. I only have one suite right now, but the problem is even when I have NO tests, it still takes like 5 seconds to run. When I run my one suite it's maybe 5.1 seconds. I'm just trying to figure out if it's supposed to take this long to bootstrap. Does it for you?